# syntax error at or near "'select to_char(application_date::timestamp, '"

Tags: postgresql

```
EXECUTE 'select to_char(application_date::timestamp, 'Mon-YY') as appl_month from my_schema.my_table;';
```

The above PostgreSQL EXECUTE statement is giving the below error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'select
>   to_char(application_date::timestamp, '" LINE 1: EXECUTE 'select
>   to_char(application_date::timestamp, 'Mon-YY...
>                   ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "'select
>   to_char(application_date::timestamp, '" SQL state: 42601 Character: 9

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Changed to below statement

```
EXECUTE 'select to_char(application_date::timestamp, ' || quote_literal(Mon-YY) || ') from standard.npo_weekly_export;';
```

But giving new error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'select to_char(application_date::timestamp, '"
LINE 1: EXECUTE 'select to_char(application_date::timestamp, ' || qu...
                ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "'select to_char(application_date::timestamp, '"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 9
```

Expected Output: - Counts by month  in Mon-YY format

```
Application month   Application #   Final Approval #    
Jan-17              1,000           800
Feb-17              1,010           808
Mar-17              1,020           816
Apr-17              1,030           824
```

If I do the below query:

```
select to_char(application_date, 'Mon-YY') as appl_month, 
    count(distinct application_id) as appl_count, 
    sum(final_approval_ind) as fa_count,
from my_schema.my_table 
group by appl_month 
order by appl_month;
```

Generated output: (**Note:** Sorted by text, not by date)

```
"Apr-17";94374;19953
"Apr-18";87446;20903
"Aug-17";102043;21536
"Aug-18";91107;20386
"Dec-17";63263;13755
"Dec-18";21358;74
"Feb-17";89447;18084
"Feb-18";75426;16144
"Jan-17";86103;16394
"Jan-18";79403;17766
"Jul-17";90380;18929
"Jul-18";85439;20186
"Jun-17";95596;20403
"Jun-18";85764;18707
"Mar-17";112929;23323
"Mar-18";91179;21841
"May-17";101907;22349
"May-18";90885;21550
"Nov-17";78284;16791
"Nov-18";80472;7656
"Oct-17";87955;18524
"Oct-18";82821;17056
"Sep-17";80740;17788
"Sep-18";75785;18009
```

**Problem:** `to_char()` returns text and it sorts by text and not by date. So the output is jumbled rather than sorted by Mon-YY.

Comment: What data type is `application_date`?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Tried with quote_literal(Mon-YY) but there is new error. Is there a way I can handle to_char patterns in dynamic-SQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: application_date is of type date

Comment: Then the cast `::timestamp` is useless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: application_date is of format YYYY-MM-DD, I need to extract Mon-YY from that date, I find that to_char converts YYYY-MM-DD to Mon-YY but returns text, so next I extract the YY part and the Mon part and order by YY and then by Mon. Still that does not answer the error that I am getting

Comment: If that column really is a `date` then it has no format. You can apply `to_date()` on a date value directly without the need of casting it. See an example here: https://rextester.com/QQABV55682

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190676/discussion-between-somnathchakrabarti-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregation in a derived table (aka "sub-query") that preserves the data type, then do the sorting in the outer query:

```
select to_char(ap_month, 'Mon-YY') as appl_month
       appl_count, 
       fa_count
from (       
  select date_trunc('month', application_date) as ap_month, 
         count(distinct application_id) as appl_count, 
         sum(final_approval_ind) as fa_count,
  from my_schema.my_table 
  group by ap_month
) t
order by ap_month;
```

`date_trunc('month', application_date)` will normalize the `application_date` to the start of the month, but will retain the `date` data type, so that the sorting in the outer query works correctly.

I have no idea what the dynamic SQL in your question is supposed to do, but if you need to use that query for whatever reasons as dynamic SQL, you need to escape the single quotes by doubling them.

```
execute '
  select to_char(ap_month, ''Mon-YY'') as appl_month
         appl_count, 
         fa_count
  from (       
    select date_trunc(''month'', application_date) as ap_month, 
           count(distinct application_id) as appl_count, 
           sum(final_approval_ind) as fa_count,
    from my_schema.my_table 
    group by ap_month
  ) t
  order by ap_month;
'; -- end of dynamic SQL
```

But using Postgres' [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) would be easier:

```
execute $dyn$
  select to_char(ap_month, 'Mon-YY') as appl_month
         appl_count, 
         fa_count
  from (       
    select date_trunc('month', application_date) as ap_month, 
           count(distinct application_id) as appl_count, 
           sum(final_approval_ind) as fa_count,
    from my_schema.my_table 
    group by ap_month
  ) t
  order by ap_month;
$dyn$; -- end of dynamic SQL
```

Note that you can nest dollar quoted strings, so if that query is used inside a function, just use a different delimiter than you use for the function body (see the [example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING))

Comment: The problem with to_char function is it returns text and if the date is now formatted as Mon-YY and I need to sort the final output by the date in Mon-YY format, it will sort by text and not by date. Please see my edit for the output after I sort using to_char.

Comment: @somnathchakrabarti: you now completely changed your question. And the use of dynamic SQL in it makes it even more confusing. What is the purpose of that `execute`?

Comment: Using dynamic SQL to load into table is a pre-condition that I can't change. That's why initially I restricted my question to how to handle to_char function in Execute statement within a SP

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion on doubling single quotes. I tried with ||'Mon-YY'||, ||quote_literal(Mon-YY)||, "Mon-YY", etc but it was giving repeated errors. Thanks again!